# What commands can I give an ICBM in order to complete my turn?

Tags: civilization-revolution-2

I'm playing my first game of Civ Rev 2 on iOS, and I've been given an ICBM for building the Manhattan Project wonder. Now that ICBM sits in one of my cities, and the game has stopped here. I can't use it, because I am a democracy. At the end of my turn, the game wants me to do something with the ICBM. If it were any other unit I could move it or fortify it or something to keep the game moving. But not this ICBM! Any ideas? I don't want to use it, I just want to keep playing!

Answer (score 1):

Just tap and hold the finger on the down right button and you will be able to end the turn